# Spawning C child process for different jobs?

Tags: c, linux, fork

So I am trying do a application which `fork()`s 2 children.

- first does a `for(i=1; i<=50000; i++)` loop
- the second a `for(i=50000; i<=100000; i++)` loop
- the parent does `for(asciic=65; asciic<=90; asciic++)`-> loop for printing A to Z letters

I need all three to do they're work simultaneous not one after another.

I've looked over the internet and I couldn't found a proper way, all I could find are loops which create the children processes but they do almost the same thing and most are created one after another.

Any help is appreciated.

To be more understood, this is what I've done before posting:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int main(void) {
    pid_t child_pid,child_pid1;
    int i=0;
    int stare;
    int asciic;

    child_pid=fork();
    child_pid1=fork();

    if (child_pid==0) {
        //printf("Father PID: %d -> Child 1: %d\n",getppid(),getpid());
        for(i=1; i<=50000; i++){
            printf("%d-%d\n",getpid(),i);
        }
        exit(0);
    } else if (child_pid1==0) {
        //printf("Father PID: %d -> Child 2: %d\n",getppid(),getpid());
        for(i=50000; i<=100000; i++) {
            printf("%d-%d\n",getpid(),i);
        }
        exit(0);
    } else {
        //printf("PID-ul procesului parinte: %d\n", getpid());
        pid_t rez=waitpid(child_pid,&stare,WNOHANG);
        pid_t rez1=waitpid(child_pid1,&stare,WNOHANG);
        while(rez==0 || rez1==0){
            for(asciic=65; asciic<=90; asciic++){
                printf("%d- %c\n",getpid(),asciic);
            }
            rez=waitpid(child_pid,&stare,WNOHANG);
            rez1=waitpid(child_pid1,&stare,WNOHANG);
        }

    }

    return 0;
}
```

If I comment out the loops I can see that the children have different PIDs, 1 child has the right parent PID and other it has other parent PID.

Comment: Did you do a search on SO?  For example, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6008249/spawn-an-independent-child

Comment: @Klas Lindbäck, yes, that is a sort of typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
child_pid=fork();
child_pid1=fork();   // This line will be executed by both parent and first child!!!
```

You need to move the second fork into the parent part of the first if, and then have a separate if for the second child.

Comment: Thank you. Your answer was the one I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Your 2 lines with forks:

```
child_pid=fork();
child_pid1=fork();
```

do not create 2 children, but three:  the parent creates a first child in the first `fork()`.  From that moment there are 2 processes: parent and child.  And each of them executes the second `fork()`.  You will have in total 1 parent, 2 children and 1 grandchild.

In order to have just 1 parent and 2 children, you will have to:

```
pid1 = fork();
if (pid1 < 0) {
    /* Error in fork() */
} else if (pid1 == 0) {
    /* first child */
    exit(0);
}

pid2 = fork();
if (pid2 < 0) {
    /* Error in fork() */
} else if (pid2 == 0) {
    /* second child */
    exit(0);
}

/* parent */
```

Moreover, even when your code is correct, you cannot "see" if the processes are running concurrently or not just looking at their outputs.  In fact, even if there are multiple processes executing "at the same time", you may see that one of the processes finishes before another one starts.  That is because typically the kernel does time multiplexing to offer each child some CPU time.  You can see concurrency if the processes take longer to complete, for example adding some `sleep()`.

Answer (score 1):

`fork()` returns the `pid_t` of the child to the caller (parent), or -1 if it failed. In the child, 0 is returned. You can simply test

```
if (fork())
    {
        //do one thing
    }
else
    {
        //do something else
    }
```

Comment: @sjnarv True. I don't really know what the OP would want to do when fork() fails though.

Comment: I am sorry but I cannot aprove your question as I do not find it what I am looking for, you just show me the code to fork the process creating 1 child. I know how to do that, I also know how to create an infinite amount of children, but I do not know how to make multiple children do totally different jobs in parallel(children as in processes which have the same getppid() as parents getpid()).