# I want to run two different main processes

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, process, multiprocess

I want to kill the 1st process then I wan to run the 2nd process. how can I do that?

I want to do in embedded linux, How can I do that? I have no idea. Any sample example would be helpful.
The 2nd process should run independently, there should not be any relation between 1st and 2nd process.

Comment: Have you looked at `fork()`? If not, do `man fork` and possibly  `man daemon`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spawn an independent child](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6008249/spawn-an-independent-child)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `fork` to create a child process and then do stuff in both processes. You don't need multiple processes for everything: you might want to read about threading vs multiprocessing.

This is an example for your scenario using `fork`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main() {
    pid_t pid = fork();
    if(pid == -1) {
        perror("fork");
        return 1;
    }

    if(pid == 0) {
        puts("hello from child process!");
    }
    else {
        puts("hello from parent process!");
    }
}
```

Comment: also if you want to kill the child process you can just use kill(pid_child) the pid of the child process is returned by fork

Comment: This still leaves a parent-child relationship between the two processes. One could do `fork()`, `setsid();` and `fork()` again to daemonize the second process.